# How to parse user input for arguments? Python

Tags: python, python-itertools

My issue is located in the middle section of the code.

```
from itertools import product
import sys
import time

color = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "blue", "green", "indigo", "violet",
         "pink", "magenta", "grey", "white", "black", "brown", "tan",
         "gold", "silver"]

sport = ["soccer", "football", "cricket", "baseball", "softball",
         "hockey", "tennis"]

adj = ["all", "one", "other", "this", "that", "more",
       "most", "first", "new", "newer", "newest", "good",
       "better", "best", "last", "own", "same", "old",
       "older", "elder", "eldest", "oldest", "little"
       ]
animal =["cat", "kitty", "kitten", "dog", "doggy", "puppy",  "elephant",
          "serval", "ocelot", "giraffe","caracal", "saiga", "viper",
          "macaw", "bear", "panda", "parrot", "kia", "gazel", "hiyena",
          "bird", "eagle", "margay", "ferret", "tapir", "agouti", "puffin",
          "baboon", "mandrill", "vulture", "lemur", "langur", "ringtail",
          "buzzard", "albatross", "seahorse", "cockroach", "otter",
          "racoon", "quail", "emu", "rhea", "cassowary", "barracuda",
          "owl", "alpaca", "gemsbok", "eel", "cheetah", "catfish",
          "pangolin", "crab", "bat", "walrus", "fox"
          ]

noun = ["number","ladder", "axe", "account", "apple", "house", "case", "system",
         "group", "party", "company", "school", "fact", "money", "point",
         "state", "night", "water", "thing", "family", "head", "hand", "order",
         "home", "power", "country", "council", "use", "service", "room", "market",
         "problem", "court", "police", "car", "vehicle", "form", "face", "education"
        ]
verb = ["writing","riding"
        ]

rng = (1000)
formnumber2 = ['{:>02d}'.format(i) for i in range(rng)]
formnumber3 = ['{:>03d}'.format(i) for i in range(rng)]
formnumber4 = ['{:>04d}'.format(i) for i in range(rng)]
formnumber5 = ['{:>05d}'.format(i) for i in range(rng)]
formnumber6 = ['{:>06d}'.format(i) for i in range(rng)]
formnumber7 = ['{:>07d}'.format(i) for i in range(rng)]
formnumber8 = ['{:>08d}'.format(i) for i in range(rng)]
formnumber9 = ['{:>09d}'.format(i) for i in range(rng)]

#def type(str):
 #   for char in str:
  #      time.sleep(.001)
   #     sys.stdout.write(char)
    #    sys.stdout.flush()

#def open_file(_fileName):
 #   rng = input("Set integer's max(Default=1000): ")
  #  with open(_fileName, 'w') as f_out:
   #     type("Please wait while I write your file...")
    #    for c in product(color):
     #       print(''.join(c), file=f_out)

def Cmd():
    print("LOADING...\n")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Enter the name of the file you'd like to create for your wordlist.\n")
    print("If a file with that name already exists, it will be overwritten.\n")
    print("Please refrain from using numbers in your filename.\n")
    fileName = "/wordlists/"+input("> ")
    """numbers = ['{:>03d}'.format(i) for i in range(999)]"""
    print()
    print("Please enter the rule arguments in the order you would like to apply them to your wordlist.\n")
    print()
    print("Rule args:| color / adjective / animal / noun / verb / number / formnumber |\n")
    print()
    print("'number' will write a number as: 1\n")
    print("while 'formnumber2' will write as: 01 ; and 'formnumber9' will write as: 000000001\n")
    print()
    print("For example:\n")
    print("            color, animal, formnumber3 | #1,646,352 words\n")
    print("            #Writes things like: redshark001 or greentiger999\n")
    print("          or\n")
    print("            noun, noun, formnumber2 | #22,498,789 words\n")
    print("            #Writes things like: roomservice02 or waterdamage999\n")
    print("          or\n")
    print("            adj, noun, number | #256,383,360 words\n")
    print("            #Writes things like: posionapple2 or ancientpalace123\n")
    args = input("> ")
    
    #split = args.split(', ')
    #print(len(split))
#please ignore this.
    #for lsts args:
     #   rng = input("Set integer's max(Default=1000): ")
      #  with open(fileName, 'w') as f_out:
       #     type("Please wait while I write your file...")
        #    for c in product(args):
         #       print(''.join(c), file=f_out)
```

I need to shorten this lower half
Do I need a for loop or something?

I'm not quite sure what I need to do to check the input for arguments.
I have a feeling its using indexing??? like args[0-4]? maybe?

As you can see above I've tried and tested a few ideas to no avail.

VVVV

```
    if "color" in args:
        rng = input("Set integer's max(Default=1000): ")
        with open(fileName, 'w') as f_out:
            type("Please wait while I write your file...")
            for c in product(color):
                print(''.join(c), file=f_out)
    
    if "color, animal, formnumber3" in args:
        rng = input("Set integer's max(Default=1000): ")
        with open(fileName, 'w') as f_out:
            type("Please wait while I write your file...")
            for c in product(color, animal, formnumber3):
                print(''.join(c), file=f_out)
                
    if "color, animal, formnumber2" in args:
        rng = input("Set integer's max(Default=1000): ")
        with open(fileName, 'w') as f_out:
            type("Please wait while I write your file...")
            for c in product(color, animal, formnumber2):
                print(''.join(c), file=f_out)

    if "color, animal, number" in args:
        rng = input("Set integer's max(Default=1000): ")
        with open(fileName, 'w') as f_out:
            type("Please wait while I write your file...")
            for c in product(color, animal, number):
                print(''.join(c), file=f_out)

    if "formnumber9" in args:
        rang = input("Set integer's max(Default=1000): ")
        rng = rang
        with open(fileName, 'w') as f_out:
            type("Please wait while I write your file...")
            for c in product(formnumber9):
                print(''.join(c), file=f_out)

    if "noun, noun, formnumber2" in args:
        rng = input("Set integer's max(Default=1000): ")
        with open(fileName, 'w') as f_out:
            type("Please wait while I write your file...")
            for c in product(noun, noun, formnumber2):
                print(''.join(c), file=f_out)

    if "adj, noun, formnumber2" in args:
        rng = input("Set integer's max(Default=1000): ")
        with open(fileName, 'w') as f_out:
            type("Please wait while I write your file...")
            for c in product(adj, noun, formnumber2):
                print(''.join(c), file=f_out)

    if "adj, noun, formnumber3" in args:
        rng = input("Set integer's max(Default=1000): ")
        with open(fileName, 'w') as f_out:
            type("Please wait while I write your file...")
            for c in product(adj, noun, formnumber3):
                print(''.join(c), file=f_out)

                

    type("All finished!\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    type("Killing this program...\n")
    time.sleep(1)
    quit()

Cmd()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html).

Comment: Are these number : `#1,646,352`, `#22,498,789` & ... used in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly for your second part with all the if statements I would suggest to use if-elif-else statements and I would also change these if statments.

For example the first if statement

```
if "color" in args:
```

This will always be true if the user types color in any format e.g if the user inputs "color, animal, formnumber3" this first if statement will be true which will be problamatic.

To fix this I would do the following (first 2 examples):

```
 if args == "color":
    #code here

elif args == "color, animal, formnumber3": # changed to elif
    #code here
```

Repeat this for your if statements

You were talking about indexing and it does as the args is of type string. Therefore args[0:6] will get the first 5 characters. The 6 is exclusive not inclusive. So if you want to use string slicing for your if statement you could like below:

```
if "color" in args[0:6]:
```

I would advise you to do some sort of checking of user input first to make sure it fits what the program expects as string slicing can throw an error if out of bounds.

For example if the string is "color" this has length 5 and therefore if you do args[0-7] it will throw an error "out of bounds". Worth doing an if statement checking the length of the input.

for example:

```
if len(args) == 5:
    #add if statements that only require 5 characters etc
elif len(args) ==9 #etc
```

To shorten your print statements I am not really sure but what I can say is to remove the empty print statments and add '\n' newline at the end of each print statement.

Answer (score 0):

If your vars exist in the global scope, you can use built-in function `globals` which returns a dictionary containing the current scope's global variables, then pass it to a function which execute the same code, but first you need to extract your `args` from user input:

```
#This will extract the user inputted args in string type
user_args = [x.strip() for x in args.split('|')[0].split(',')]

#Retrieve actual vars from globlas
filtered_args = map(lambda arg: globals().get(arg), user_args)

#Pass them to your function
def print_product(filtered_args):
    rng = input("Set integer's max(Default=1000): ")
    with open(fileName, 'w') as f_out:
        print("Please wait while I write your file...")
        for c in product(*filtered_args):
            print(''.join(c), file=f_out)
```

Another approach is to build a dictionary containing pointers to your vars, for example:

```
vars_dict = {'noun':noun, 'color': color, 'verb':verb, 
             'formnumber2':formnumber2, 'animal':animal, 'sport':sport}
```

Then retrieve from this `dict` the user inputted args and pass them to `print_product`.